# Is BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId) always unique?

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, bson

Just a straight forward question is

```
[BsonId]
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
```

always unique? If not is there a way to generate a unique id for my user?

Answer (score 2):

The rule formation for a objectid is:

The 12-byte [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#examples) value consists of:

- a 4-byte timestamp value, representing the ObjectId’s creation, measured in seconds since the Unix epoch
- a 5-byte random value
- a 3-byte incrementing counter, initialized to a random value

If you want to know more, there is [this article](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/generating-globally-unique-identifiers-for-use-with-mongodb) that explains in detail how to avoid that situation.